# macOS 11 Launch Agent can't access NFS shares

Tags: macos, launchd, macos-big-sur, launch-daemon, launchdagent

I am trying to set up a launch agent on macOS 11 to run a script on an NFS share. My launch agent works when the script is located on the local computer but fails with `Operation not permitted` when the script is located on NFS. Is it possible to give launchd access to NFS shares?